# Replace NULL with a some string

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database which looks like:

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| ProductName | Status  | Branch |
+-------------+---------+--------+
| P1          | dead    |      1 |
| P1          | dead    |      2 |
| P2          | expired |      1 |
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

I want to show the result after comparison of products as:

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| ProductName | Branch 1|Branch 2|
+-------------+---------+--------+
| P1          | dead    |    dead|
| P2          | expired |    OK  |
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

After I run the following query:

```
<pre>
SELECT  ProductName,
MAX(CASE 
WHEN Branch=1 
THEN Status
ELSE NULL 
END) AS 'Branch 1',
MAX(CASE 
WHEN Branch=2
THEN Status
ELSE NULL 
END) AS 'Branch 2'
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY ProductName;
```

I get result as:

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| ProductName | Branch 1|Branch 2|
+-------------+---------+--------+
| P1          | dead    |    dead|
| P2          | expired |    NULL|  
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbe96/4)
I want to replace NULL with OK but couldn't manage to get the desired result. Kindly point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` to escape null

```
SELECT  ProductName,
      COALESCE(  MAX(CASE 
            WHEN Branch=1 
            THEN Status
            ELSE NULL 
        END) ,'OK') AS 'Branch 1',
       COALESCE( MAX(CASE 
            WHEN Branch=2
            THEN Status
            ELSE NULL 
        END),'OK') AS 'Branch 2'
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY ProductName;
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbe96/12)

Comment: Can you please explain me in easy words that how COALESCE works.I have read the literature but couldn't manage to grasp the exact concept.

Comment: @Hasnain The `COALESCE()` function returns the first non-null value it is passed. For a straight forward example, `COALESCE(null, 5)` would return 5. `COALESCE(10, 5)` would return 10.

Comment: @MCAdam331 now i got it. Thank you so much!